# Guidance For Implementing A Circular Progress Bar in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swift

After finding myself inspired by the upcoming [Workout app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KUAu.jpg) for iOS/Apple Watch, I found myself dissecting what appears to be a UITableView with this circular progress indicator.  I've seen some circular progress indicators online ([iOS-Circle-ProgressView](https://github.com/CardinalNow/iOS-CircleProgressView)) but have been unsuccessful in implementing this into a custom cell in my UITableView.

I'm intersted in implementing the above into my project, but my attempts to import it seem to result in a blank space in the cell, and no circular indicator.

Is it possible to implement such an item inside a custom cell?  Or would it have to live in its own view controller?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the frames and colors, there should be no problem at adding the indicator to your tableview cells. Updating them might be the tricky part depending on what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Put a `UIView` on your custom cell and assign a custom class file to that view. In that class file override `drawRect()` and you are completely free on what gets displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  @zisoft!  That totally worked!  Thank you!